# deny directory listing with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a folder, for example : `/public_html/Davood/`
and too many sub folder in folder, for example : `/public_html/Davood/Test1/` , `/public_html/Davood/Test1/Test/` , `/public_html/Davood/Test2/` , ...

I want add a htaccess file into `/public_html/Davood/` To deny DirectoryListing in `/Davood` and sub folders. It's possible?

Comment: I don't see why `Options All -Indexes` didn't work as in few answers!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr it's depend to webserver configuration, if `AllowOverride All`, works

Comment: `Options -Indexes` is the good solution. But there are multiple other solutions you can use with htaccess to deny directory listing .. see here https://helponnet.com/2021/07/29/apache-disable-directory-listing/

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Options -Indexes** should work to prevent directory listings.

If you are using a .htaccess file make sure you have at least the "allowoverride options" setting in your main [apache config file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: this doesnt change anything

Answer (score 100):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in that directory.

```
Options -Indexes
```

[This](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/) has more information.

Comment: Yeah I thought -Indexes disabled directory listings, instead it blocks all content from the folder ... Does anyone know why?

Comment: All I can think is there's some problem with server config. Try enabling `rewrite` module, and directory setting to `AllowOverride All`. If all that is already in place, and what you commented is true, I must be just too lucky to get `Options All -Indexes` to work in every project on different servers.

Comment: If there is just `Options -Indexes` it might be error 500 in some servers. There should have some condition (`if`) to prevent this.

Answer (score 36):

If `Options -Indexes` does not work as Bryan Drewery suggested, you could write a recursive method to create blank index.php files.

Place this inside of your base folder you wish to protect, you can name it whatever (I would recommend index.php)

```php
<?php

recurse(".");

function recurse($path){
    foreach(scandir($path) as $o){
        if($o != "." && $o != ".."){
            $full = $path . "/" . $o;
            if(is_dir($full)){
                if(!file_exists($full . "/index.php")){
                    file_put_contents($full . "/index.php", "");
                }
                recurse($full);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

These blank index.php files can be easily deleted or overwritten, and they'll keep your directories from being listable.

Comment: Although an empty file is not that big of a deal, a better solution might be to use [symbolic links](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php), that way it saves a bit of space, and he would only need to modify 1 file if he chose to display some sort of uniform message instead of a blank page.

Answer (score 29):

For showing Forbidden error then include these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If we want to index our files and showing them with some information, then use:

```
IndexOptions -FancyIndexing
```

If we want for some particular extension not to show, then:

```
IndexIgnore *.zip *.css
```

Comment: .htaccess in root directory.

Answer (score 25):

**Options -Indexes**  perfectly works for me ,

here is `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes <---- This Works for Me :)
    </IfModule>


   ....etc stuff

</IfModule>
```

Before : [image]

After :

[image]

Comment: is there any particular reason why you nested `IfModule mod_negotiation` in `IfModule mod_rewrite.c`?

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways :

1. using .htaccess : `Options -Indexes`
2. create blank index.html

Answer (score 6):

```
Options -Indexes
```

I have to try create .htaccess file that current directory that i want to disallow directory index listing. But, sorry i don't know about recursive in .htaccess code.

Try it.

Answer (score 4):

Agree that

```
Options -Indexes
```

should work if the main server is configured to allow option overrides, but if not, this will hide all files from the listing (so every directory appears empty):

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 2):

**Options -Indexes** returns a 403 forbidden error for a protected directory. The same behaviour can be achived by using the following Redirect in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

This will return a forbidden error for **example.com/folder/** .

You can also use mod-rewrite to forbid a request for folder.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [F]
```

If your htaccess is in the folder that you are going to forbid , change RewriteRule's pattern from **^folder/?$** to **^$** .

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a .htaccess file to prevent directory listing. If .htaccess is not enabled on your server, enable it. Inside the apache configuration file or your virtual host file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

where /var/www/html is the root directory. This will enable the use of .htaccess file on your server. Inside the .htaccess file add the following at the top:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the browsing/indexation of directories.