# how restrict the files in directory listing in hosting

Tags: php, hosting

For my website example.com try to use subdomain  as download directory as media.example.com 
but when i uploaded some files to that media file in public_html folder.when i visit the media.example.com it list all the files in that directory.

I also tried .htaccess and .htpasswd but it ask password and allow me in , but when i click the link of uploaded directory it show error.

What i need is ?

example.com and my download files to be in media.example.com/

File link -->  media.example.com/downloads/apps/xyz.zip  ( when user click they can download)

problem   --> media.example.com/downloads/apps/    it shows all files link ( It should not display the list of files -  needs to show error )

How to hide those files link in directory but public users should download files of link can be downloaded by single click.

Anyone help me..,

Comment: possible duplicate of [deny directory listing with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

You can then set an error page to show the user (error 403):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/error403.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess file (providing you're using Apache) place this line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will disable directory listing to that directory