# styles not applied when using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I put this piece of code in the `includes` directory to avoid users having access to its content:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

and I use the code below to redirect error 403 to particular error page,this is place in parent root (`website`) of the `includes` directory:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
```

... but the styles don't apply to the pages.  What is the problem?

Note: the errors directory is placed in "website" and "styles" directory placed in "includes" directory

Answer (score 1):

As you deny the access to the includes folder, the users browser is not able to get the files in your styles folder, assuming the CSS stylesheets necessary for styling the page. Instead it receives an error 403 "Forbidden".

See [deny directory listing with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess) if you want to disable directory listing and thus only allow the user to access files directly.