# standard method for redirect on manual input url

Tags: php, security, url

So i'm wondering how you professionals go about securing your website by not allowing a user to manually input a url to a certain folder such as website.com/images/ and view a directory listing. The method i've been using is placing an index.php file and using this code, which just brings the user back to main homepage. But i feel like there is probably an easier way to do this. Possibly Server Side?

```
<?php
ob_start();
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: ../index.php');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dupe of another question, i really don't have a clue what i would search to answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use htaccess to prevent direct access

create .htaccess file add this `Options -Indexes` line . add it in your project root path

These links  may help you 
1. [deny directory listing with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess)
2. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/