# how to stop everyone can see my folder on website?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I use magento and It worked fine.Then I migrated my website to another hosting and when I go to Url `www.mywebsite.com/skin` or some folder and it show my website folder to everyone

It should be Show `404 error page` in my custom theme

Please help me how to redirect `www.mywebsite.com/skin` to my `404 error page` theme

Sorry for my bad english and I'm very new to website coding.

Comment: does this hosting allows you to change the root `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Possible related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess?lq=1

Comment: if your .htaccess is not allowed you can just add a index.html or index.htm file on each folder.Make the page look like your 404 page.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes i can edit my .htaccess file

Comment: Sounds like your transfer method did not move your .htaccess files from your old installation. It's common where people think FTP is a usable method to move everything from the test site to the new site. It often isn't because *nix hidden files (files starting with .) are hidden to the FTP client unless you change a configuration setting. .htaccess files are scattered all through Magento's directories to prevent this kind of access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code in .htaccess. It blocks the folders to be seen if no index file inside it.

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: your method works!  and another folder already show Forbidden page but but when I go to www.mywebsite.com/js it shows SYNTAX: index.php/x.js?f=dir1/file1.js,dir2/file2.js

Comment: Go expand out Magento's install package somewhere on your local disk, find all the .htaccess files and make sure they're copied to the proper locations on your live Magento install.

Answer (score 0):

put a `.htaccess` file in any folder you want to restrict it to the user and paste below code at the top.

```
deny from all
```