# permissions of web folder set to rwxr-xr-x but all file are visible

Tags: php, file, web, permissions

I have multiple website on my server.
In one of them I noticed i can see all the php files (and their code) of a folder.

The folder permissions are rwxr-xr-x (0755) and the files inside are rw-r--r-- (0644).

In my second website I have a similar folder and files with the same file permissions but there i get :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /myFolder/ on this server.
```

How is it possible?
and what is the best way to set permissions so the website users can see the website but not a whole folder files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this in .htaccess file in that directory.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Info: [deny directory listing with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess)

Info: http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/

Comment: Yeah that'll work but is that the only way a user can see my php files? through the directory listing?

Comment: Or if the user has access to the server ... I do not remember another way that they can see your files ... it never happened to me: P