# How can i restrict a folder that i create in root directory in a codeigniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http

*I have a codeigniter project. If i create a folder in root direct that can't provide codeigniter framework by default, if i hit a url with **base_url + folder_name(http://localhost/Magpie/css/)** as a result browser will shown all the file in this folder **screenshot** attach in bellow :*

> **How can i Manage this problem**

[image]

---

> Already I used a .htaccess file in project root directory. 
>   my **.htaccess** code in bellow :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Magpie/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Right, and what's your question?

Comment: Create an empty index.html file in it, people wont be able to see files when you access it through browser

Comment: Or look into `.htaccess` and deny from all on the root of this dir

Comment: have any another way @UmarKhan?

Comment: The other way could be deny from .htaccess

Comment: what's the problem in my question? @Utkanos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deny directory listing with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your .htaccess with this

I have just added **Options -Indexes** in you .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Magpie/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your .htaccess file and add below line on top

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you create a extra folder that can't provide codeigniter framework by default.*

*To restrict the folder's all file follow the next Step :*

**Step-1**

*create a .htaccess file into the folder*

**Step-2**

*save this line of code that provide in bellow:*

```
 Options -Indexes
```

[image]

**Step-3**

Now  Run your Project