# Denying access to a specific url using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I do not use any framework
I have a folder named 'uploads' and a sub-folder named images that i upload my images in
It's obvious that I want users to access some images, but if users try to load, for example, this URL:

**'example.com/uploads/'**

they have access to all my images

so my question is where should I upload my images?
or how can I deny access to a specific URL?

Comment: I think this is something like `Options -Indexes` to be added to your .htaccess file?

Comment: please add index.php file in images folder. It will restrict by to access all images on browser.

Comment: thank you "dineshkashera"... that's a practically good idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .htaccess file for the folder, which should have denied access with

Deny from  all

Comment: If I do that, user can not have access to some images... I want them to have access to images but not folders