# .htaccess stop directory listing and forward to handler.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to implement SEO friendly URLs using .htaccess and PHP.
I have achieved 90% of my goal and struggling with just one use case.

Here is what happing, when I access the following url

```
http://somesite.com/cms/movies/tarzan
```

it lands on

```
my-handler.php?the_url=movies/tarzan
```

This is perfect and that is what I want because then I manage it myself. The real problem is when I don't provide any slugs, then it lists the directory (means show all files and folders in it)

`http://somesite.com/cms/`

Can someone please help me fix following .htaccess content, so that even if I don't provide slug it should still be handled by my-handler.php instead of lisiting full directory?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/
RewriteRule ^my-handler\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/my-handler.php?the_url=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

> Solved

As per **@Roman** suggestion, I added the following to the above listing and it solved my problem. Plus I do not have to compromise on accessing physical directories `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

```
DirectoryIndex my-handler.php
```

Comment: You need to disable directory listing and set the `DirectoryIndex` to `DirectoryIndex my-handler.php`. This question could help you with the listing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess

Comment: i have added an answer with some more details. ✌️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to set the `DirectoryIndex` to handle every request which points to `/` with your `my-handler.php`. This can be done by adding the line  to your `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex my-handler.php
```

To disable the directory listing, you have to forbid the listing by adding the following line to your `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```

Remember that this configuration is per `.htaccess` and just for the directory you are placing the file in. If you want to make changes for your whole webserver, you can edit the `httpd.conf` and search for

```
Options Indexes
```

and remove the `Indexes` option.

### Documentation

The listing is provided by the [mod_autoindex module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

### Nice side-fact

If you just want to disable the listing of specific file-types like `.env` or `.php` files, you can add the option `IndexIgnore *.php` to you `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/
RewriteRule ^my-handler\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|json|woff|ttf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/my-handler.php?the_url=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think the above method will stop me from accessing physical directories like `xyz/somefile.php`